# calling <reified T> inline functions from a class

Tags: kotlin, generics, gson

in short : I want to create a generic class of Type `T` that should be calling  a reified inline function of type `T` to be able to use Gson more generically

in details:
Hello. I had recently started using kotlin for Android dev, and i was trying to create a generic network client class. The class would fetch the data from server, convert the response into a datatype provided by the generic class's type and return the response, something like this:

```kotlin
class GenericNetworkService<RESPONSE_TYPE> {

    fun getDataFromServer(url: String): RESPONSE_TYPE {
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()

        val convertor = Gson()

        val result: RESPONSE_TYPE = convertor.fromJson(response.body!!.string(), RESPONSE_TYPE)

        return result

    }
}

//calling
//fun main() {

//    val listOfPersons = GenericNetworkService<List<Person>>().getDataFromServer(url1)
//    println(listOfPersons)

//    val listOFTeacher = GenericNetworkService<List<Teacher>>().getDataFromServer(url2)
//    println(listOFTeacher)
// }
```

here , only the `gson.fromJson()` func is the one which is actually needing the details of the class in which the final output has to be converted . **But it doesn't takes the generic type into second parameter, so the above program would not work.**
After searching through some internet articles, i came across this`TypeToken` Api which helps achieve generic behavior upto certain extent:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> fromJson(json: String): T {
   return Gson().fromJson(json, object: TypeToken<T>(){}.type)
}

//calling : 
// val data : List<Teacher> = fromJson(response)
```

using inline reified functions, i am able to achieve everything i originally want:

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified RESPONSE_TYPE> getGenericRespSync(url: String): RESPONSE_TYPE {
    val okHttpClient = generateNetworkClient()
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val response: Response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()

    val body: Reader = response.body!!.charStream()
    val finalResponse: RESPONSE_TYPE =  getConvertedListForResponse(body) //this is the same reified inline function as above with some non signinficant additions
    return finalResponse
}
```

But i  want my other classes to call this function via some class instance. i.e something like `GenericNetworkService<List<Person>>().getGenericRespSync(url1)` should be returning List and not the direct call to `getGenericRespSync(url1)` . How can i achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can define

```
inline fun <reified RESPONSE_TYPE> GenericNetworkService<RESPONSE_TYPE>.getGenericRespSync1(url: String): RESPONSE_TYPE = getGenericRespSync<RESPONSE_TYPE>(url)
```

(I named the function differently so it can call your previously defined `getGenericRespSync`). Of course, it only uses the instance it's called on to get its type parameter and ignores it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, class constructors can not use the same `reified` mechanism as inline functions can. However, you can define your type as regular constructor parameter and create new instances  of your class using a top level inline function

```
class GenericNetworkService<RESPONSE_TYPE>(private val responseTypeClass: Class<RESPONSE_TYPE>) {

    fun getDataFromServer(url: String): RESPONSE_TYPE {
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()

        val convertor = Gson()

        val result: RESPONSE_TYPE = convertor.fromJson(response.body!!.string(), responseTypeClass)

        return result

    }
}

inline fun <reified RESPONSE_TYPE> createService() = GenericNetworkService(RESPONSE_TYPE::class.java)
```

Of course, you can also rename `createService` to `GenericNetworkService` so it looks like a constructor. This is becoming more common in kotlin, especially if you look at the coroutines core code, so I wouldn't consider this an anti-pattern anymore.